# An error occurred. Please try again later. in facebook app

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

Facebook allows to authorize my app for only Administrators but while authorizing my app by other user its shows an error 'An error occurred. Please try again later.'

Comment: Did you have a question?  Preferably one on-topic for SO?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your facebook application page(https://developers.facebook.com/), There is a option called `sandbox mode` disable it.

If the option is enabled, ie if the application is in sandbox mode only the owner(admin) can use it, it needs to be in disabled for user to use it.

[image]

Comment: It is in disabled mode.. but still the error occurs, only the Administrators get authorize but not other :(

Comment: @sudeep777: If you are disabled it now, I guess it may take some time, wait for some time and check again

Comment: I can't seem to disable Sandbox Mode. I get this error: "Error
Category is required when Sandbox Mode is disabled. You can set a Category for this app in the App Details section of the App Dashboard." But when I try to set a Category, I get to a blank page with just the text "Please try again later." How do I get out of this limbo?

Comment: @sudeep777 You have to go to App Details page to change your app category to any category other than "other".